# Match a string in java replace it and get the integer from it

Tags: java, string, oop, replace

I am trying to find and replace a part of the string which contains an integer.

```
String str = "I <FS:20>am in trouble.</FS>";
```

I need to replace  and 
for /FS I am using

```
str = str.replace("</FS>", "\\fs0");
```

I am not sure how to approach the FS:20 because the 20 is a variable and in some cases might be a different number which means that I need to somehow the int part.

Input :

```
"I FS:20 am in trouble.";
```

Output :

```
"I \fs20 am in trouble.";
```

but 20 is not a fixed variable so I can't hardcode it

Comment: What are you trying to replace it with?

Comment: is it clear now

Comment: Try this it works with matches() :
str = str.replace("</FS>", "<FS:\d*>");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to make two replacements:

```
str = str.replaceAll("</FS>", "");
str = str.replaceAll("<FS:(\\d+)>", "\\\\fs$1");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
I \fs20am in trouble.
```

The first replacement just removes `</FS>` from the string.

The second replacement makes use of a `RegEx` pattern `<FS:(\d+)>`.

[image]

The `RegEx` pattern matches the literal characters `<FS:` followed by one or more digits, which it stores in group 1 `(\d+)`, finally followed by the character `>`

The value stored in group 1 can be used in the replacement string using `$1`, so `\\\\fs$1` will be a backslash `\` followed by `fs` followed by the contents of group 1 `(\d+)`, in this case 20.

The numbers matched by `\d+` are stored in group 1, accessed using `$1`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use your variable that is 20 in described case.

```
    Integer yourVariable=20;
    String str = "I <FS:20>am in trouble.</FS>";
    str = str.replace("<FS:"+yourVariable+">", "\\fs0");
```